# iText: Evince does not display the content of the cell

Tags: pdf-generation, itext

Following the simple exaple: http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/101-very-simple-table#1488-simpletable.java Evince does not display the content of the cell. Is it a bug of iText output or Evince?

Comment: You may assume that all examples on developers.itextpdf.com have been verified with Adobe Reader. Have you tried viewing the file with other pdf viewers? Correct me if I'm wrong, but Evince is only available for Linux, right?  Which version of Evince are you using? I'm currently the only Linux user at the iText office (Xubuntu), but I don't have Evince installed either. So if you tell me the version, I'll see if I can look at it in the morning.

Comment: Yes I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Evince from standard  repository version 3.10.3

Answer (score 1):

I have just executed the example you refer to. This is what the result looks like:

[image]

This is what I expect to see.

I have then opened Preflight in Adobe Acrobat:

[image]

As you can see, I selected the option to "Report PDF syntax issues". This is the result when I ran this operation:

[image]

According to Preflight in Adobe Acrobat, there isn't anything wrong with that PDF file. This is what I expected. iText already exists for almost 16 years. iText Group has thousands of customers. Hundreds of thousands developers have been using iText. 8% of every PDF on the world is created using iText. It would very much surprise me if an example as simple as this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it looks in Evince 3.16.1. Looks OK to me.

[image: Evince 3.16.1]

Please try again with a more recent version of Evince.
Also compare with the `cmp_` file that you can find below every example.

- If the problem goes away, then it was probably a bug in Evince that has since been solved.
- If the problem persists, then you didn't follow the example as you should. In that case, post the exact `.java` file as you have it on your system. It could be something like a simple typo in your code.